# Cómo cambiar color a menu al pasar el mouse por encima. Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Hola estaba probando este código en la pestaña "css adicional"

```
.a:hover{
   color:#1717FF
}
```

pero no me cambia, ¿cuál podría ser el error?

Gracias.

Comment: Hola, debes poner más contexto. ¿`.a` es una clase css? Si lo es, ¿a qué elemento se la estás aplicando? Saludos

Comment: <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content">Ir al contenido</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema lo tienes en que **"a" no es una clase**, sinó que **tiene** una clase.

a class="screen-reader-text .....  por lo tanto, prueba así:

```
a.screen-reader-text:hover {color:#1717FF}
```

Con ésto estás diciendo que el a, **con la clase screen-reader-text**, al hacer hover, cambia el color a #1717FF

Si no te funciona, prueba con la segunta clase que tiene a (skip-link) y te quedaría así:

```
a.skip-link:hover {color:#1717FF}
```

Y si así y todo no te funciona (los themes de WP son rarísimos, a veces), dale prioridad con fuerza bruta: **!important** aunque no deberías abusar de ésto

```
a.screen-reader-text:hover {color:#1717FF !important}
```

Comment: Ya probe las 3 opciones en el css adicional pero no me cambia, sigue con el mismo color predeterminado por el tema. Probe cambiarle el color a un boton pero tampoco lo cambia...

Comment: Es lo que tiene WP y sus plantillas. **Visita el Foro de WP** sobre tu tema, a ver que solución encuentras ( https://es.wordpress.org/support/forum/temas-y-plantillas/ )

Comment: **Rafael** aquí tienes algo de ayuda extra https://www.silocreativo.com/como-modificar-anadir-css-tema-wordpress/

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, muchas gracias por la ayuda :D

Comment: Hola **Rafael**. ¿Y cómo lo haz solucionado...?. Aquí se trata de que otros (que puedan tener dudas similares a las tuyas), puedan encontrar una guía para resolver sus problemas. Quizás respondiendo a tu propia pregunta con el fragmento de código sea suficiente. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Si sirve, lo que sucede que el color #1717FF, es casi el mismo azul que el de los enlaces y por eso no notas la diferencia, pero si le pones negro a las etiquetas  verás el cambio

Basicamente lo tienes así:

```css
a:hover {
  color: #1717FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">index</a>
```

Pero que pasa si le establecemos un color que no sea azul, para distinguir el hover

```css
a:hover {
  color: #07d544;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">index</a>
```

En conclusión si tu quieres un color azul en el hover, primero debes establecer un color base distinto al azul para las etiquetas , se debe a que por defecto los enlaces son de color azul, este caso podría ser un color base negro y el hover #1717FF (azul) quedaría así:

```css
a{
  color: #000;
}
a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #1717FF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">index</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por la atencion la solucion fue la siguiente

```
a:hover{
color:#002646 !important;
```

}

La clave fue el !important.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a{
  color: #FFBB5C;
}
a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #C63D2F;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html">ESTO_ES_UNA_PRUEBA_PHP.php</a>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).